# How to simultaneously highlight multiple areas on an image map

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, imagemap

I am using [David Lynch's fabulous MapHighlight plugin](http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/) with a custom version of a U.S. map. Unfortunately, some U.S. States (like Rhode Island) are extremely small. For this reason, I created boxes to the right of the map with abbreviations for some of these smaller States.

What I would like to be able to do is to have both the box and the map highlight at the same time when a user hovers over either the box or the State.

```
<area href="#" title="RI" shape="poly" coords="617,141, 617,138, 617,135, 616,131, 620,130, 621,131, 623,133, 625,136, 623,138, 622,137, 622,139, 620,140, 617,141, 617,141"/>
<area href="#" title="RI" shape="rect" coords="728,164,760,182"/>
```

Both items share the same time title. (For example, the title tag for Rhode Island is "RI")

Based on a sample on David Lynch's site, I thought perhaps it might be useful to do something like the following.

```
$('area[title]').mouseover(function() {
   $(this).mouseover();     
});
```

Unfortunately, this did not work and the event never seemed to fire--even though I tried a number of variations.

What can I do to synchronize these elements (in a generic way) and have all area tags with the same title to all highlight on mouseover/hover?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try ImageMapster out: http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster

The default behavior should do what you want (see the demos page - the first example is a USA map).

In a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/juvyh/

Answer (score 3):

I'm aware this is an old question, however as explained in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577190/groupby-function-in-maphilight-jquery-plugin):
The maphilight function has a groupBy function. In your case you could do something like:

```
$('.mapimage').maphilight({ groupBy: 'title' });
```

Which will group by the area's title (although you can select any attribute of the area).

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
$('area').mouseover(function() {
    $('area[title="'+$(this).attr('title')+'"]').mouseover();
});
```

This handles the `mouseover` event on all `area` elements and then uses the title attribute to trigger the `mouseover` event on all matching areas with the same title

Comment: it looks like a great solution. Unfortunately, no events related to area ever seem to be firing. I am stumped. :(